# How to return SQL Server stored procedure results to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I can verify that my VBA code is executing the stored procedure at the server but I'm unable to get the recordset back into Excel.

```
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & ServerName & ";...."//works 
set rs = cmd.Execute(, SP_Param, adCmdStoredProc) // executes
If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(4, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
//tosses Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

I've tried using the `SQLOLEDB` provider but am unable to get through to the stored procedure using that.

Relevant references:

- ActiveX Data Object Recordset 6.0 Lib
- ActiveX DataObjects 6.1
- ActiveX Remote Data Services 6.0

Comment: Any chance there is no records in table ?

Comment: What's your stored proc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the beginning of your SQL Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is the problem but you should try setting NOCOUNT ON in the proc to make sure that is not the problem.

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```